# Understanding Large Object Heap and stats output by DumpHeap

Tags: sos, large-object-heap

Say I have following class:

```
Class A
{
 B b;
 C c;
 D d;
}
```

First, I allocate:

```
var b1 = new B();
var c1 = new C();
var d1 = new D();
```

each of `b1, c1, d1` is less than 85K, so they get allocated on the small object heap.
Then I do:

```
var a1 = new A { b = b1, c = c1, d = d1 };
```

Question1: When I do `!DumpHeap -stat` does the mem usage of `A` include memory occupied by its member variables? If not, what does it actually include?
EDIT: found answer to this question in this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2005/11/25/dumpheap-stat-explained-debugging-net-leaks.aspx. It makes sense that mem usage of `A` does NOT include memory occupied by `b1, c1, d1`. It includes the memory needed to store the `b1, c1, d1` references themselves.

Question2: Does `a1` get allocated on the large object heap (assume size of `b1 + c1 + d1` > 85K)? Why? The references `b1, c1, d1` point to objects on small object heap. Then why would `a1` sit on the LOH?

Question3: Lets flip it around. Say size of `b1` is more than 85K, so its allocated on the LOH. But to store references to `b1, c1, d1` we only need a few bytes. Am I correct in believing that `a1` will be allocated on the small object heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As you have already found out the size of the instance of A does not include the size of the referenced objects. However, if you want to find out the size use the `!objsize` command. Keep in mind that if multiple objects reference the same other objects the size of these will be included multiple times.

2) The object referenced by `a1` does not get allocated on the LOH. The object itself is less than 85000 bytes, so it is allocated on the regular heap. Use the `!gcwhere` command to list what part of the heap a given object is in.

3) It doesn't matter if the `b1` reference points to a large object. The size of any instance of `A` will only be three references plus some additional overhead (a reference to the type object and a syncblock). I.e. the size will be very far from the LOH limit.